# clang-tidy: What is the check to detect memory leak due to missing free before throw?

Tags: clang-tidy

Is there a check / configuration to detect memory leak due to missing free before throw as in following code using clang-tidy?

Clang detects if free is missing before end of the block / function `ASN_STRUCT_FREE(asn_DEF_ConnectionResponse, resp);`.

```
asn_encode_to_new_buffer_result_t RLDReqConnection::encodeResponse()
{
ConnectionResponse_t *resp;
resp = static_cast<ConnectionResponse_t*> (calloc(1, sizeof(ConnectionResponse_t)));
if (resp == nullptr) {
    throw RLDException(1065, "Out of memory");
}

int numDevices = m_devices.size();
resp->devices.list.array = static_cast<IA5String_t**> (calloc(numDevices, sizeof(IA5String_t*)));
if (resp->devices.list.array == nullptr) {
    **//!!!MISSING free (resp);**
    throw RLDException(1065, "Out of memory");
}

asn_encode_to_new_buffer_result_t enc_rval;
//...code left for brevity

ASN_STRUCT_FREE(asn_DEF_ConnectionResponse, resp);

return enc_rval;
}
```

But can't figure out a way to catch  **//!!!MISSING free (resp);** when function returns in between like in case of throw.

Checks used with `clang-tidy` are `-checks=clang-analyzer-*,google-*,modernize-*,-clang-analyzer-alpha.*`

Comment: cppcheck detects this.